# AngularJs Bootstrap Datepicker Popup custom date onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-bootstrap

I am using AngularJs Bootstrap datepicker and what I'm trying to do is to add a date which I have in a variable.

Here is the url: [Datepicker Homepage](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup)

So for example:

```
var myDate = '2017-12-12';
```

Then I have this:

```
$scope.today = function() {
  $scope.dt = new Date();
}
```

The code about is adding today's current date and I want to add the value of the variable to the datepicker input.

So I've tried:

```
$scope.dt = new Date(myDate);
```

But this is not populating the datepicker input with the new date.

So my question is...How do I get this done?

Comment: Try same with `initDate` in datepicker options. Also can you create a plunker for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date constructor does not know how to convert your string to a proper date object.

Try it like this

```
var myDate = '2017-12-12';
var dtArray = myDate.split("-");
$scope.dt = new Date(dtArray[0], dtArray[1] - 1, dtArray[2]);
```

*NOTE: The month is counted from 0-11, thats why we need to add minus one*